# relationship between elliptic curves over $\mathbb{C}$ & Weierstrass $\wp$-function

Tags: algebraic-geometry, elliptic-curves, riemann-surfaces, elliptic-functions

I'm studying about elliptic curves over $\mathbb{C}$, then at some point the Weierstrass $\wp$-function appear. It appears to show that:

1) $\wp$ and $\wp'$ generate the field of meromorphic functions on $\mathbb{C}/\Lambda$;

2)$\wp'(z)^{2}=4\wp(z)^{3}-g_{2}\wp(z) -g_{3}$;

3)$z \rightarrow (1,\wp(z),\wp'(z))$ is an isomorphism.

My question is that I can not see why exactly this function appears. What is the reason for proving these facts 1), 2) and 3) in relation to Weierstrass $\wp$-function.It is not clear to me the purpose of proving 1), 2) and 3) ...

I sorry if this question is trivial

Comment: I think that an appropriate answer to your question must depend on what your understanding of “elliptic curve over $\Bbb C$” is. So I ask: what, for you, is an elliptic curve?

Comment: I'm reading Silverman's book; The arithmetic of elliptic curve. I start considering that a elliptic curve $E$ is curves of genus one having a specified base point. Then, through the Riemann-Roch theorem, we have that $E$ can be represented by equation $y^{2}=x(x-1)(x-\lambda)$.

Comment: But is an elliptic curve a function field in one variable over some constant field ($\Bbb C$ in this case) and of genus one? Or is it a compact complex variety of dimension one and genus one? If all you want is a function field, then it’s $\Bbb C(\wp,\wp')$. If you want a complex variety, it’s $\Bbb C/\Lambda$. Anyhow, pay attention to @ReneSchipperus’s response. That’s plenty good.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At the simplest level it is a parameterisation. For example the circle $$x^2+y^2=1$$ is parameterized by 
$$x=\cos z$$
$$y=\sin z.$$

Similarity, the elliptic curve 
$$y^2=4x^3-g_2x-g_3$$ is parameterised by

$$x=\wp(z)$$
$$y=\wp^{\prime}(z)$$

More sophisticated point of view I that the $\wp$ function arises by integrating the only holomorphic differential over the curve. Historically the two ideas grew up together. In other words all statements about curves have their function theoretic analogs, for example addition of points is a rational addition property for elliptic functions.